# Devise: Extend an Existing App with Pepper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, password-encryption

I have a working app with Devise already configured. The problem is that I didn't configure the *pepper* option before and there are already users registered on the app live instance.

I need to add `config.pepper` to my Devise configuration to increase security.

From my tests I noticed that existing users wouldn't be able to log in anymore with their password.

How do I migrate already registered users?

What are the best practices to add a *pepper* configuration to an already existing app?